# Need duplicate next button event of stepper in custom button in react material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using horizontal stepper from material UI and integrated in my react app. In all steps i am having different forms and submit button, i need to trigger next button event on form submit button click.
I tried various options but unable to duplicate next event on form submit button.

Example:-

In step 1:

```
<form>
<input type=text>
.
.
.
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Same type of form in all steps.
(Stepper next button is outside form)

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue ?

Many Thanks in advance..